# Get a integer value from HEX data

Tags: c#, binary, hex, data-conversion

I have Hex data as

```
Byte[] data = new Byte[2];
data[0]=FF;
data[1]=FF;
```

Here the binary representation of this data is as

```
1111 1111 1111 1111
```

Here i want to find the integer value from bit 0 to 11 only. (From left to right) But i am not getting how to find value with minimal complexity? Please help me.Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want only specific bits, you can apply a logical AND with a bit mask.
In your case the bit mask is 0000 1111 1111 1111 (bits zero to and including eleven) or 0FFF.

You mention "from left to right", so maybe instead you want 1111 1111 1111 0000 (FFF0) - bits 4 up to and including 15.

Comment: Hi,thanks for reply. But here i want to bit 0 to 11 from left to right. Here i want the integer value of only 12 bits(means 1111 1111 1111 ) not of all bits(means 1111 1111 1111 0000). As per your solution it gives the value of 16 bits but i want only 12 bits.

Comment: You have to mask a value that consists of 16 bits. The mask selects 12 of them. After the logical AND, 12 out of 16 bits have been selected, and that's how you get the value.

Comment: HI i tried that but the value of 1111 1111 1111 0000 is 65520  while i want the value of only 12 bits means 1111 1111 1111 and its value is 4095. So how i will calculate that? I want 12 bits value from left to right.

Comment: Ok, what do you mean with "left to right"? The value of each separate bit?

Comment: suppose I have 16 bit value as 1111 1111 1111 1111. Here i want the value of first 12 bits from left to right (Means i want the value of only 1111 1111 1111). How i can find that? As per your masking logic i am getting the value of 16 bits(1111 1111 1111 0000).

Comment: Your input is a 16 bit value. The mask selects 12 of them. The last 4 zeroes are masked out; their value is ignored in the result. That's the point of masking. Search for "bitwise AND" or look at [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bitwise_operation#AND) for details.

Answer (score 1):

```
short value = 0xFFFF;
value = value & 0x0FFF;
```

This operation turns four higher bits to 0. You can tur your char `val[1] = val[1] & 0x0F`

Answer (score 0):

Converting byte array to string:

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(ba.Length * 2);
foreach (byte b in ba)
{
       sb.AppendFormat("{0:x2}", b)
}
return sb.ToString();
```

then, parsing string to int

```
 int a = int.Parse("10026AB0", NumberStyles.AllowHexSpecifier);
```

Comment: Apart from that, i can't understand how that is supposed to work

Answer (score 0):

This is basic stuff...

you don't have "hex" data, but 2 byte sized integers.

in pseudocode ( i don't speak c# fluently) :

```
int value=data[1]<<8 | data[0];
int maskedvalue=value & 4095; // bits 0..11 inclusive set
```

now maskedvalue holds the value with only the lower 11 bits set.